# How do the two assumptions of the conditioned intensity function imply the three points?

Tags: probability

The intensity function is defined as

$$\lambda^*(t)=\frac{f(t|H_{t_n})}{1-F(t|H_{t_n})}$$ where $f$ is the density function and $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, and $H_{t_n}$ is the history of all the previous points of $t$ up to $t_n$. Moreover, there is proven that $F(t|H_{t_n})$ is also given as:

$$F(t|H_{t_n})=1-e^{-\int_{t_n}^t\lambda^*(s)ds}$$.

An assumption is then made, saying that

1. $\lambda^*(t)$ is non-negative and is integrable on every interval after $t_n$.
2. $\int_{t_n}^t\lambda^*(s)ds \to \infty$ for $t \to \infty$.

It is then said, hence the three points follows:

1. $0 \leq F(t|H_{t_n}) \leq 1$
2. $F(t|H_{t_n})$ is a non-decreasing function of $t$.
3. $F(t|H_{t_n}) \to 1$ for $t \to \infty$
   Can someone explain to me how these three points follow given the two assumptions above? Thank you.

P.s. This is a paper concerning evolutionary temporal point processes. Moreover, it's a proof which I'm trying to understand; The proof's objective is to show that $F$ is in fact a cumulative distribution function. The proof is then done given the three points. However, I can't seem to find the correct arguments that are used to explain how these two assumptions imply the three points.

Comment: When you sweep out an area under a non-negative curve, the area increases.  The rest is just properties of the exponential function and probability density functions.

Comment: So $F$ is non-negative because the we know that $\lambda^*(t)$ is non-negative and this implies that e^{-\int_{t_n}^t \lambda(s)ds} is non-negative, right? But why do we know, that $F \to 1$ for $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Exponentials (of real numbers) are *always* non-negative.  Since $F$ is a cdf, the law of total probability implies it reaches $1$ asymptotically.

Comment: @Whuber: But we want to proof that $F$ IS a cdf, and which is done by concluding that these three points follow. Therefore, I think that it would be wrong to say that $F \leq 1$ according to the LTP since we yet didn't proof that $F$ actually is a cdf.

Comment: Something is missing from your question, then, because at the outset it *states* "$F$ is the cumulative distribution function."

Comment: @whuber: Ah I see...I might have formulated the question a bit wrongly then. The paper which I'm reading is in this link arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00221.pdf in page 9. Of course that's only if you like to see the actual proposition and the proof, such that it is more clear how it was done. Because I am a bit confused how the proof was done.

Comment: The conclusions are immediate from properties of the exponential function $t\to \exp(-t).$  The only things you need to know about it are that it decreases from $1$ asymptotically to $0$ as its argument grows from $0$ to $\infty.$